# Estimating standard deviation of underlying distribution

Tags: inference, standard-deviation, bootstrap

I need to estimate the standard deviation of an underlying normal distribution. I have the following statistics of one sample: mean, min and max, standard deviation, and sample size; however, I do not have the individual points of the sample.

**Is it possible to estimate the standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution from the sample statistics I have?**

I am specifically looking to find a confidence interval for the standard deviation of the underlying distribution.

I believe bootstrap is a method that would allow me to accomplish what I need, but I am unsure as to whether I can generate my own sample distribution based on the statistics (mean, std dev) I have, and then do bootstrap on that to build a confidence interval for the statistic of interest.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the sample size?

Comment: Yes, I do have the sample size. I'll add that to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Then I suggest watching the JBStatistics video on YouTube for how to calculate a confidence interval for the variance. Then you can take the square root of the endpoints of that confidence interval to get a confidence interval for the standard deviation. $\text{//}$ Some kind of simulation where you draw observations from an $N(\bar{x}, s^2)$ distribution could work, but it is not necessary and is unlikely to get you better results.

Comment: If $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$ then $Var(\bar X) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i).$ So if the $X_i$ are IID with $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2,$ then $Var(\bar X) = \frac{1}{n^2}n\sigma^2 = \sigma^2/n.$